# Scroll div to element on click on navigation

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

Below is the code. I am not that good in jQuery. I have done this code by using google.

What I need is when user clicks on the nav for any tab. `.scrollBox` should scroll to that title.

[Here is my code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPyLMV)

Here is the jQuery

```
jQuery('.nav a').click(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
            return false
        }
        var thisId = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active');

        var scrollPosition = $('h3.'+ thisId).offset().top 
            jQuery(".scrollBox").animate({
            scrollTop:  scrollPosition
            });
        return false
    })
```

Comment: Please paste a snippet of your code, not just the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
 $("nav a").on(click, function (ev) {
         element = ev.currentTarget;               
         $(".scrollBox").scrollTo($(element), 1000, {
            step:function() {
               // NOTHING
                }
         });
    });
```

Comment: I want it when clicked on "nav a" and not on ".scrollBox"